# Shifting timeseries data using per group using shift() and groupby() results in NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

Given the following dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'YearMo': ['01', '02', '01', '02', '01', '02'],
        'Prod': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
        'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
)
```

I'm trying to lag data per year/prod group. It is my understanding this can be done using `shift()` after a `groupby()`, as follows:

```
df['shifteddata'] = df.groupby(['YearMo', 'Prod'])['Value'].shift()
```

The result of this however is a column containing NaN.

```
print(df)
  YearMo Prod  Value  shifteddata
0     01    a      1          NaN
1     02    a      2          NaN
2     01    b      3          NaN
3     02    b      4          NaN
4     01    c      5          NaN
5     02    c      6          NaN
```

Whereas I am expecting

```
  YearMo Prod  Value  shifteddata
0     01    a      1          NaN
1     02    a      2          1
2     01    b      3          NaN
3     02    b      4          3
4     01    c      5          NaN
5     02    c      6          5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `df.groupby('Prod')['Value'].shift()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are missing the fact that groups defined by `.groupby(['YearMo', 'Prod'])` are groups consisting of only one item. Shift of one item returns `NaN`s.

Your desired output can be reached by the following code:

```
df['shifteddata'] = df.groupby(['Prod'])['Value'].shift()
```

Comment: This solved it. Thanks! Cannot believe I missed this.

Comment: @Rob, I am glad it helped.